# Couldn't open the website through selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu

I'm unable to open the browser website and resulted the whole code couldn't run. I couldn't figure out the problem because there is no error printed out on the terminal too. 
My code will need to extract event details from the website by using xPath, and need to loop through the main page and get the list of all the event details.

Your help will be most appreciated!

```
    import sys
    import os
    import selenium 
    import csv
    import contextlib
    import time
    from selenium import webdriver
    from time import sleep
    from collections import defaultdict
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException,TimeoutException
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

    try:
       from urlparse import urljoin
       from urllib import urlretrieve
    except ImportError:
       from urllib.parse import urljoin
       from urllib.request import urlretrieve

    host = "http://www.sportshub.com.sg/sportshubtix/Pages/Home.aspx"

    #xPath & CSS selectors
    xpath_load_more_button = "//*[@id='togglercal-CalListslide1']/span[1]"
    name = '//*[@id="eventCalendarScroll"]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/div[1]/div/dl/dt/a'
    date = '//*[@id="eventCalendarScroll"]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/div[1]/div/dl/dd[1]/div'
    venue = '//*[@id="eventCalendarScroll"]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/div[1]/div/dl/dd[2]/div'
    description = '//*[@id="eventCalendarScroll"]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/div[1]/div/dl/dd[3]/div'

    class Crawler(object):
        def __init__(self):
             self.data = defaultdict(list)

        def start(self):
           self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
           #self.driver.implicitly_wait(1)

        def load_main_page(self):
            self.driver.get(host)

        def load_page(self, url):
            self.driver.get(url)

        def load_more_page(self):
           try:
               self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_load_more_button).click()
            return True
        except (NoSuchElementException):
            return False

    def get_name(self):
        try:
            event_name = [n.text for n in self.driver.find_element_xpath(name)]
            self.data["event_names"] = self.remove_duplicate(self.data["event_names"] + event_name)
        except:
           print("event invalid")

    def remove_duplicate(self, x):
        result = []
        for i in x:
            if i != "":
               if i not in result:
                result.append(i)


    def crawler(self, event):
        self.data["event_names"] = event
        #self.data["dates"] = []
        #self.data["time"] = []
        #self.data["venues"] = []
        #self.data["description"] = []
        print('Crawling Events = {}'.format(event))
        self.load_main_page()

def main():
    crawler = Crawler()
    crawler.start()

main()
```

Comment: Can you share the error stack trace? If no error observed set the Trace level logs & try to get some info. Else you have to Debug your code to find what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In start function, add self.crawler().
Then that function will initiate after calling driver variable. Then the browser will go to the url